# Vue ChartKick Donut custom cutoutPercentage

Tags: vuejs2, chart.js, chartkick

I'm starting to learn vue but I can't figure out how to customize a Chart with vue chartkick. What I want to do is to pass default options to change the default style of the charts, let's say I want a different cutoutPercentage, with Charts.js we can set:

`Chart.defaults.doughnut.cutoutPercentage = 10;`

But this doesn't seem to work with chartkick, I created this [Pen](https://codepen.io/ryansegus/pen/PRxrXj) to play around but I cannot figured it out, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*chart kick* allows you to pass the library options to the chart, using `:library`

```
<pie-chart :data="[['Blueberry', 44], ['Strawberry', 23]]" :donut="true" :library="{cutoutPercentage: 20}"></pie-chart>
```

https://codepen.io/BoyWithSilverWings/pen/YadXNO

Comment: It works, thanks, there's any way to set this as a global property? Like having all charts with the same cutoutPercentage: 20 ?

Comment: This Chartkick.options = {library: {cutoutPercentage: 80,}}; Worked for all of them, thanks again.